# Insert an IF function into a Excel calendar macro's entry cells

Tags: excel, vba

This is two part question.

I'd like to use the macro (provided by Microsoft because I don't know VBA at all) that populates a monthly calendar based on the month and year provided by the user. Code as follows:
Sub CalendarMaker()

```
   ' Unprotect sheet if had previous calendar to prevent error.
   ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=False, _
      Scenarios:=False
   ' Prevent screen flashing while drawing calendar.
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   ' Set up error trapping.
   On Error GoTo MyErrorTrap
   ' Clear area a1:g14 including any previous calendar.
   Range("a1:g14").Clear
   ' Use InputBox to get desired month and year and set variable
   ' MyInput.
   MyInput = InputBox("Type in Month and year for Calendar ")
   ' Allow user to end macro with Cancel in InputBox.
   If MyInput = "" Then Exit Sub
   ' Get the date value of the beginning of inputted month.
   StartDay = DateValue(MyInput)
   ' Check if valid date but not the first of the month
   ' -- if so, reset StartDay to first day of month.
   If Day(StartDay) <> 1 Then
       StartDay = DateValue(Month(StartDay) & "/1/" & _
           Year(StartDay))
   End If
   ' Prepare cell for Month and Year as fully spelled out.
   Range("a1").NumberFormat = "mmmm yyyy"
   ' Center the Month and Year label across a1:g1 with appropriate
   ' size, height and bolding.
   With Range("a1:g1")
       .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
       .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
       .Font.Size = 18
       .Font.Bold = True
       .RowHeight = 35
   End With
   ' Prepare a2:g2 for day of week labels with centering, size,
   ' height and bolding.
   With Range("a2:g2")
       .ColumnWidth = 20
       .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
       .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
       .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
       .Orientation = xlHorizontal
       .Font.Size = 12
       .Font.Bold = True
       .RowHeight = 20
   End With
   ' Put days of week in a2:g2.
   Range("a2") = "Sunday"
   Range("b2") = "Monday"
   Range("c2") = "Tuesday"
   Range("d2") = "Wednesday"
   Range("e2") = "Thursday"
   Range("f2") = "Friday"
   Range("g2") = "Saturday"
   ' Prepare a3:g7 for dates with left/top alignment, size, height
   ' and bolding.
   With Range("a3:g8")
       .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
       .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
       .Font.Size = 18
       .Font.Bold = True
       .RowHeight = 21
   End With
   ' Put inputted month and year fully spelling out into "a1".
   Range("a1").Value = Application.Text(MyInput, "mmmm yyyy")
   ' Set variable and get which day of the week the month starts.
   DayofWeek = Weekday(StartDay)
   ' Set variables to identify the year and month as separate
   ' variables.
   CurYear = Year(StartDay)
   CurMonth = Month(StartDay)
   ' Set variable and calculate the first day of the next month.
   FinalDay = DateSerial(CurYear, CurMonth + 1, 1)
   ' Place a "1" in cell position of the first day of the chosen
   ' month based on DayofWeek.
   Select Case DayofWeek
       Case 1
           Range("a3").Value = 1
       Case 2
           Range("b3").Value = 1
       Case 3
           Range("c3").Value = 1
       Case 4
           Range("d3").Value = 1
       Case 5
           Range("e3").Value = 1
       Case 6
           Range("f3").Value = 1
       Case 7
           Range("g3").Value = 1
   End Select
   ' Loop through range a3:g8 incrementing each cell after the "1"
   ' cell.
   For Each cell In Range("a3:g8")
       RowCell = cell.Row
       ColCell = cell.Column
       ' Do if "1" is in first column.
       If cell.Column = 1 And cell.Row = 3 Then
       ' Do if current cell is not in 1st column.
       ElseIf cell.Column <> 1 Then
           If cell.Offset(0, -1).Value >= 1 Then
               cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value + 1
               ' Stop when the last day of the month has been
               ' entered.
               If cell.Value > (FinalDay - StartDay) Then
                   cell.Value = ""
                   ' Exit loop when calendar has correct number of
                   ' days shown.
                   Exit For
               End If
           End If
       ' Do only if current cell is not in Row 3 and is in Column 1.
       ElseIf cell.Row > 3 And cell.Column = 1 Then
           cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1, 6).Value + 1
           ' Stop when the last day of the month has been entered.
           If cell.Value > (FinalDay - StartDay) Then
               cell.Value = ""
               ' Exit loop when calendar has correct number of days
               ' shown.
               Exit For
           End If
       End If
   Next

   ' Create Entry cells, format them centered, wrap text, and border
   ' around days.
   For x = 0 To 5
       Range("A4").Offset(x * 2, 0).EntireRow.Insert
       With Range("A4:G4").Offset(x * 2, 0)
           .RowHeight = 65
           .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
           .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
           .WrapText = True
           .Font.Size = 10
           .Font.Bold = False
           ' Unlock these cells to be able to enter text later after
           ' sheet is protected.
           .Locked = False
       End With
       ' Put border around the block of dates.
       With Range("A3").Offset(x * 2, 0).Resize(2, _
       7).Borders(xlLeft)
           .Weight = xlThick
           .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
       End With

       With Range("A3").Offset(x * 2, 0).Resize(2, _
       7).Borders(xlRight)
           .Weight = xlThick
           .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
       End With
       Range("A3").Offset(x * 2, 0).Resize(2, 7).BorderAround _
          Weight:=xlThick, ColorIndex:=xlAutomatic
   Next
   If Range("A13").Value = "" Then Range("A13").Offset(0, 0) _
      .Resize(2, 8).EntireRow.Delete
   ' Turn off gridlines.
   ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
   ' Protect sheet to prevent overwriting the dates.
   ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, _
      Scenarios:=True

   ' Resize window to show all of calendar (may have to be adjusted
   ' for video configuration).
   ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
   ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1

   ' Allow screen to redraw with calendar showing.
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   ' Prevent going to error trap unless error found by exiting Sub
   ' here.
   Exit Sub
```

' Error causes msgbox to indicate the problem, provides new input box,
   ' and resumes at the line that caused the error.
MyErrorTrap:
       MsgBox "You may not have entered your Month and Year correctly." _
           & Chr(13) & "Spell the Month correctly" _
           & " (or use 3 letter abbreviation)" _
           & Chr(13) & "and 4 digits for the Year"
       MyInput = InputBox("Type in Month and year for Calendar")
       If MyInput = "" Then Exit Sub
       Resume
   End Sub

But I need to add a function that inserts copy from another sheet in the workbook into the entry cells, defined in the code above as Range("A4:G4").Offset(x * 2, 0), when the macro is run. The copy from the other sheet is the food item in the cafeteria for the day, it is dependent on when the first day of the month is. I've built the function below, but don't know how to make it repeat for each entry cell (which is determined by cells A3:G3, A5:G5, A7:G7, A9:G9 and A11:G11) without just finding and replacing for all of those (I'm familiar with JavaScript, so I'd assume an array could work for this?) and fit into the macro I'm trying to use above, since if I put it into the cells in the Calendar View worksheet it is overwritten when the macro is run.

=IF(E3=1,'Menu Items'!B2,IF(E3=2,'Menu Items'!B3,IF(E3=3,'Menu Items'!B4,IF(E3=4,'Menu Items'!B5, IF(E3=5, 'Menu Items'!B6, IF(E3=6, 'Menu Items'!B7, IF(E3=7, MenuItems!B8, IF(E3=8, 'Menu Items'!B9( IF E3=9, 'Menu Items'!B10, IF(E3=10, 'Menu Items'!B11, IF(E3=11, 'Menu Items'!B12, IF(E3=12, 'Menu Items'!B13,IF( E3=13, ‘Menu Items’!B14, IF(E3=14, ‘Menu Items’!B15, IF(E3=15, ‘Menu Items’!B16, IF(E3=16, ‘Menu Items’!B17, IF(E3=17, ‘Menu Items’!B18, IF(E3=18, ‘Menu Items’!B19, IF(E3=19, ‘Menu Items’!B20, IF(E3=20, ‘Menu Items’!B21, IF(E3=21, ‘Menu Items’!B22, IF(E3=22, ‘Menu Items’!B23, IF(E3=23, ‘Menu Items’!B24, IF(E3=24, ‘Menu Items’!B25, IF(E3=25, ‘Menu Items’!B26, IF(E3=26, ‘Menu Items’!B27, IF(E3=27, ‘Menu Items’!B28, IF(E3=28, ‘Menu Items’!B29, IF(E3=29, ‘Menu Items’!B30, IF(E3=30, ‘Menu Items’!B31, IF(E3=31, ‘Menu Items’!B32, IF(E3=0, “ “))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Thanks so much!